# How to make axes ticks in between grid lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

In my simple example below, how to make x-axis tick values to appear between grids?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1)
x = range(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(x)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The following make ticks to be where I want but the grid lines also moves.

```
np.random.seed(1)
x = range(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(x)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xticks(np.arange(10)+0.5, x)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like the result to be:
[image]

Comment: You need to set a seed when you use random functions, so that your output will be "random", but with consistent results. See [`np.random.seed()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the minor ticks so that only 1 minor tick appears inbetween your major ticks. This is done using [`matplotlib.ticker.AutoMinorLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html%23matplotlib.ticker.AutoMinorLocator). Then, set the gridlines to only appear at the minor ticks. You also need to shift your xtick positions by 0.5:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator

np.random.seed(10)

x = range(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5,10.5,1), x)
plt.xlim(0,9.5)
plt.ylim(0,1)
minor_locator = AutoMinorLocator(2)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator)
plt.grid(which='minor')

plt.show()
```

[image]

**Edit**: I'm having trouble getting two `AutoMinorLocator`s to work on the same axis. When trying to add in another one for the y axis, the minor ticks get messed up. A work around I have found is to manually set the locations of the minor ticks using a [`matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator) and passing in the locations of the minor ticks.

```
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator
np.random.seed(10)

x = range(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5,10.5,1), x)
plt.yticks([0.05,0.15,0.25,0.35,0.45,0.55,0.65,0.75,0.85,0.95,1.05], [0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1])
plt.xlim(0,9.5)
plt.ylim(0,1.05)

minor_locator1 = AutoMinorLocator(2)
minor_locator2 = FixedLocator([0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1])
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator1)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator2)
plt.grid(which='minor')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but, looks like this approach moves the grid. Is there a way to move **labels** not the grid?

Comment: Can you provide an example image of where you would like the ticks and where you would like the grid lines because it's not 100% clear to me

Comment: Sorry, I added the desired outcome as a picture at the end of the question above.

Comment: @DavidG, thanks. This already helped a lot. Is there a way to do the same thing for the y-axis? To have grids at 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, etc, but the labels 0.1, 0.2, etc in between grids?

Answer (score 0):

If you use plt.subplots for figure creation, you get an axes object, too:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
```

This one has a better Interface for adjusting grid/ticks. Then you can give explicitly x-values for your data shifted 0.5 to the left. The same do with the minor ticks and let the grid be shown at the minor ticks:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.set_xticks(range(10))
x_values = np.arange(10) - .5
ax.plot(x_values, np.random.random(10))
ax.set_xticks(x_values, minor=True)
ax.grid(which='minor')
```

[image]

Comment: I want the values 0, 1, 2, etc. to appear **in between** grid lines.

Comment: Thanks, but this approach also moves the grids not labels! please let me know if you know a way to move the labels.